# simple scrolling images in android in an single activity

Tags: android

How to obtain the below functionality in android?

Images are coming from an external url. How to attain simple scrolling ?

For Placing the buttons i have an idea

But for Scrollable images below, how to obtain this functionality. Which concept should i need to apply?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your layout wrap the images in a horizontal LinearLayout and those as your rows in a vertical layout then wrap that in a HorizontalScrollView. So you'd have something that looks similar to this:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
                <Images... />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
                <Images.. />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a `horizontalScrollView`. I guess it'll solve your purpose. Place the images in the horizontalScrollView and inside it you may take a `TableLayout`. Don't specify the width of it. Just specify the `layout_weight`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scrollview horizontally` and then inside it you setup `linearlayout` and `imageviews` in them.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/cone" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/cone" />            

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/cone" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/cone" />            

    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```